# Parsing Javascript Date to java.utils.date.Date

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, date

I have a service provide dates and i need process this in mi Android App

In my Node server:

```
server.send({'date': new Date() });
```

In my android app:

```
Date date = new Date(jsonObject.getString('date'));
```

this throws me a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` error

if a print in the android Log i get `2013-02-21T17:55:27.885Z` how to handle this format

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: yes but i don't know how to handle `27.885Z`

Comment: That is there in the documentation - ss.SSS

Comment: If you can change the server code then use new `Date().getTime()` to get the time in milliseconds, no need to parse anything.

Comment: @ebarrenchea if i get the dates from a MongoDB database date.getTime() works fine?

Comment: I don't know since I've never used MongoDB before. Any function or method call that gives you the time in milliseconds can be used straight away to create an instance of `Date` without any parsing required. If you have no control over the backend then parse the date string.

Comment: I use the Date.getTime() for now works fine

Answer (score 1):

Store your `Date` as a long using

```
date.getTime()
```

making your calls look like this:

```
server.send({'date': new Date().getTime() });
```

and

```
Date date = new Date(jsonObject.getString('date'));
```

Comment: after the @ebarrenchea comment That's what I did

Comment: @Phil new Date(dateString) is deprecated

Comment: @Qamar I wrote this back in 2013. I don't have the docs in front of me right now - but I know that *Calendar* is replacing all or at least a large portion of *Date*. Have a look there for which method to use instead.